# Comparing two ArrayLists and remove duplicates from original ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two Custom `Arraylist`:

```
List<Item> before = new ArrayList<Item>();
List<ItemEx> after = new ArrayList<ItemEx>();

before.add(new Item(1L,"test1"));
before.add(new Item(2L,"test2"));
before.add(new Item(3L,"test3"));

after.add(new ItemEx(1L,"test4"));
after.add(new ItemEx(2L,"test5"));
after.add(new ItemEx(4L,"test6")); 
after.add(new ItemEx(5L,"test7"));
```

I want to store the elements in the `List<ItemEx> after` and the element shoulds be after the removing of common element is `{3L, 4L, 5L}`.

Comment: add items from both list into HASHSET, after that you get only, 1L,2L,3L,4L,5Lin hashset

Comment: `after.removeAll(before)` works if you can somehow compare the objects correctly (maybe override .equals method). @DivyeshPatel how does this remove common elements from `after` list?

Comment: HASHSET allows only unique entry, so it store only unique data

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i want to remove the common elements.

Comment: @ShikhaRatra check my answer

Answer (score 2):

**FYI**

**`List<Item>`** & **`List<ItemEx>`** should be **SAME TYPE** .

**Logic**

```
List<String> before = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> after = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<String> list_checking = new ArrayList<String>(before);
                            list_checking.addAll(after);
                            List<String> list_common = new ArrayList<String>(before);
                            list_common.retainAll(after);
                            list_checking.removeAll(list_common);
```

Comment: my `ArrayList` is not of same type

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(before);
hs.addAll(after);
after.clear();
after.addAll(hs);
```

Now, in after list you get desire values.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Take a copy of the existing one into a temporary Variable if you want for future use.

ArrayList temporiginalArrList=OriginalArrayList; 
//here 'T' can be a specific object to want to save

OriginalArrayList.removeAll(secondArrayList);